# Endpoint for Email validation

Tags: validation, email, endpoint

Does anyone know an endpoint to validate emails and avoid the bounce rate?

I am testing with this platform https://isitarealemail.com/, however it is not well known and I don't know if it is reliable to use it

Answer (score 0):

Use RegEx instead.

```js
function ValidateEmail(mail) 
{
 if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(myForm.emailAddr.value))
  {
    return (true)
  }
    alert("You have entered an invalid email address!")
    return (false)
}
```